# Is there a package that has the "clockwise gapped circle arrow" in it?

Tags: symbols

The symbol I'm after is ⟳ (also nice to have ⟲).  That's `U+27F3` (and `U+27F2`).  [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) can't find it (or my drawing skills are woeful); is it already in a font package, or do I have to load it from STIX?

A more general question would be: if I already know the unicode symbol, how do I find out which package supports it?

Comment: Note: I feel sure we've had this one before, but I couldn't find it.  If anyone can find it, I'll happily join the "duplicate" throng.

Comment: It wouldn't be too hard to draw it in TikZ, but I guess that's not the point...

Comment: Have a look at [“How to look up a math symbol?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found them in **MnSymbol** as `\lcirclearrowright` and `\rcirclearrowleft`. Either use the similar symbols in **mathabx**, rotating and reflecting them, or go with these and
[my answer on how to import a symbol from a different font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font/14406#14406)

Using the latter way has the advantage that the symbols change size in subscripts and superscripts. Of course it's easy to do this also with the **mathabx** symbols (via `\mathchoice`).

Answer (score 21):

Can also be rotated with less or more than 180 degrees

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathabx,graphicx}
\def\Circlearrowleft{\ensuremath{%
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\circlearrowleft$}}}
\def\Circlearrowright{\ensuremath{%
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\circlearrowright$}}}
\def\CircleArrowleft{\ensuremath{%
  \reflectbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\circlearrowleft$}}}}
\def\CircleArrowright{\ensuremath{%
  \reflectbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\circlearrowright$}}}}
\begin{document}
\Huge
$\circlearrowleft \circlearrowright $

$\Circlearrowleft \Circlearrowright $

$\CircleArrowleft \CircleArrowright $
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the symbols I want, I guess I'd want to rotate them by 90 degrees.  (I notice that `mathabx` defines `\righttoleftarrow` which is _almost_ what I want except that it isn't circular.)

Comment: `\circlearrowleft` is already contained in amsmath, no need to load `mathabx`.

Comment: @Carambir: It is in `amssymb`, not `amsmath` and it is not the same, the lines are less thick

Answer (score 11):

For future reference: finding special symbols, in particular if you know their names, is fairly straightforward using the [**`symbols`** documentation](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/) (`texdoc symbols` in a terminal).

Searching the document for “circlearrow” (or “circle arrow”) yielded the `MnSymbol` package and the macro names. Some viewers (e.g. Skim on OS X) even support searching for Unicode symbols, and searching for “⟳” also worked.

Comment: I've gotten so used to detexify that I figure that if it doesn't even come close then it isn't in `symbols` so I('m ashamed to say I) didn't look there!  But I wouldn't have known what to search for since I didn't know about the unicode search facility (have to check that in Linux PDF readers) and I didn't know their names.