# How to put a symbol inside a circle arrow?

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols

I'm trying to draw a [clockwise circle arrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21334/is-there-a-package-that-has-the-clockwise-gapped-circle-arrow-in-it) with a symbol inside. My current solution requires manual alignment of the content, and as such doesn't look very good.

```
\makebox[0pt][l]{\huge$\circlearrowright$}\ $i_3$ }
```

[image: circle arrow with content]

Is there a solution which doesn't require manual correction? If not, is there a method to have more fine-grained control over the horizontal alignment, and any control at all over the vertical?

Comment: Related Question: [Drawing a circle around a node that looks like an arrow](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76058/drawing-a-circle-around-a-node-that-looks-like-an-arrow).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is slightly automated solution using `tikz`. I measure the height and width of the text and place an arc whose size is based on the maximum of that.  Am sure this can be improved, but this should get you started:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}

\makeatletter
\newlength\@SizeOfCirc%
\newcommand{\CricArrowRight}[1]{%
    \setlength{\@SizeOfCirc}{\maxof{\widthof{#1}}{\heightof{#1}}}%
    \tikz [x=1.0ex,y=1.0ex,line width=.15ex, draw=blue]%
        \draw [->,anchor=center]%
            node (0,0) {#1}%
            (0,1.2\@SizeOfCirc) arc (85:-240:1.2\@SizeOfCirc);%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\CricArrowRight{$i$}
\CricArrowRight{$i_3$}
\CricArrowRight{$\frac{a}{b}$}
\CricArrowRight{$\dfrac{a}{b}$}
\end{document}
```

I created a temporary length `\@SizeOfCirc` so as to minimize potential name conflicts, and need to use `\maktatother`. See [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do) for more info if you are not familiar with that.

Comment: Very flexible, and I learnt some TiKZ. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This may be satisfying, if the symbol to put inside is not too big

```
\usepackage{relsize}
\newcommand\cca[1]{{%
  \ooalign{\raisebox{-.4ex}{\larger[4]$\circlearrowright$}\cr
    \hidewidth$\,#1$\hidewidth}}}
```

Then `\cca{i_{3}}` should do what you need.

Look at [Subseteq+circ as a single symbol "open subset"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22371/subseteq-circ-as-a-single-symbol-open-subset) for details about `\ooalign`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is manual way of doing it that allows some freedom in terms of fine-tuning the vertical movement:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\begin{document}
\setbox1=\hbox{\huge$\circlearrowright$}%
\setbox2=\hbox{$i_3$}%
\makebox[0pt][c]{\usebox1}% Place \circlearrowright
\makebox[0pt][c]{\raisebox{2.5pt}{$i_3$}}% Overlay label
\hspace{0.5\wd1} Here is some more text.
\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[image: Overlayed symbols]

The zero-width `\makebox`es have their contents centered `[c]`. Both elements are placed stored in a box (`box1` and `box2` respectively) so that you can use their widths (`\wd1` and `\wd2`) or heights (`\ht1` and `\ht2`) if needed.