# How to put a symbol inside another in math mode?

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols

In math mode, I would like to put a symbol inside another.
Let say I want to put an x inside a V.
I would like x to be in the empty space inside the letter V.
I guess I need to put V in a box, then x in a box too,
and strecth/quench/overlap each box.

I look at this thread, [How to put a symbol inside a circle arrow?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29841/16609).
I tried the following, but it is not nice looking

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\setbox1=\hbox{$V$}
\setbox2=\hbox{$x$}
\makebox[0pt][c]{\usebox1}
\makebox[0pt][r]{\raisebox{2.5pt}{$x$}}
\hspace{0.5\wd1} Here is some more text.
\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[image: latex result]

Comment: Just curious... What do you need that for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be a starter using `\kern` and `\raisebox`. You may experiment with the dimensions:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newcommand*{\xV}{{\large V}\kern-0.55em\raisebox{1.4ex}{\tiny x}}
\begin{document}
\xV
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The `\ooalign` primitive can be used to overlap symbols horizontally (I've learned at least that much in my time here!), rather than having to use boxes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\Vx}{%
  \ooalign{\Large $V$\cr\hss\raisebox{1.4ex}{\scriptsize $x$}\hss}}%
\begin{document}
Here is some more text. \Vx
\end{document}
```

Vertical adjustment comes from `\raisebox{<len>}{<stuff>}`, as needed.

Comment: Why not `$\scriptstyle x$`? I'd use `\hidewidth` instead of `\hss`.