# Create curved TikZ single arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to create a curved single arrow inside some circles indicating rotation. Currently I'm doing it using the `\draw arc` but the result is very ugly, the arrow tip is very weird when I make the arrow thick. Since each of the arrows must have different thickness, I can't just make them thin.

This is what I have right now:
[image]

I'd like the arrows to look like the arrow at the bottom but with varying thickness, which is created with the `single arrow` from the tikzlibrary `shapes.arrows`.

This is my current code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} %[>=latex]

% cross
\draw[gray,line width=3pt,opacity=0.5,line cap=round] (-2,0) -- (2,0);
\draw[gray,line width=3pt,opacity=0.5,line cap=round] (0,-2) -- (0,2);

%rotors
\draw[inner sep=3pt,outer sep=0,fill=blue,fill opacity=0.3,draw=blue] (-2,0) circle     [radius=1cm];
\draw[inner sep=3pt,outer sep=0,fill=blue,fill opacity=0.3,draw=blue] (2,0) circle     [radius=1cm];
\draw[inner sep=3pt,outer sep=0,fill=red,fill opacity=0.3,draw=red] (0,-2) circle [radius=1cm];
\draw[inner sep=3pt,outer sep=0,fill=red,fill opacity=0.3,draw=red] (0,2) circle [radius=1cm];

% rotation direction arrows
\draw [->,line width=5pt] (-2.4,0.3) arc[x radius=0.5cm, y radius =.5cm, start angle=-220, end angle=40];
\draw [->,line width=1pt] (1.6,0.3) arc[x radius=0.5cm, y radius =.5cm, start angle=-220, end angle=40];
\draw [<-,line width=2.5pt] (-0.4,-1.7) arc[x radius=0.5cm, y radius =.5cm, start angle=-220, end angle=40];
\draw [<-,line width=2.5pt] (-0.4,2.3) arc[x radius=0.5cm, y radius =.5cm, start angle=-220, end angle=40];

% rotors asterisk to indicate front and side
\draw plot[mark=asterisk,mark size=5pt,mark options={color=red}] coordinates {(-2,0)};
\draw plot[mark=asterisk,mark size=5pt,mark options={color=green}] coordinates {(2,0)};
\draw plot[mark=asterisk,mark size=5pt,mark options={color=cyan}] coordinates {(0,-2)};
\draw plot[mark=asterisk,mark size=5pt,mark options={color=red}] coordinates {(0,2)};

% translation direction
\node[fill=black,single arrow,minimum height=3cm] (arrow)  at (0,-3.5){};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Repositioning and resizing arrow tip on circular (arc) path](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/76073/14500).

Comment: @PaulGaborit this questions originally asks for a curved single arrow, not for tip positioning. It came out, however, that curved single arrows seem not possible.

Comment: `curved single arrow` shape does not exist... but it may be possible to create one.

Comment: @PaulGaborit I thought it was possible after seeing this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75432/curved-text-on-multiple-lines-within-curved-arrow-using-tikz. It is about text, but there is definitely a curved arrow in there. Although I don't understand how that was made, I thought it would be possible to do the same here.

Comment: In the linked question, the arrow head is made via `-latex` and `line width=5ex`. This arrow head is not curved.

Comment: @PaulGaborit The head is not, but the arrow itself is. Isn't it possible to draw a circled arrow like these from my picture using the same structured as in the linked question? I can't see why not, but right now I don't understand the code from the linked example either, so I'm might be wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is due to the large curvature with thick linewidth. TikZ makes some inner calculations before putting the arrow heads such as measuring the finishing angle and going a little backwards to make sure the arrow head joins the lineend nicely etc. I think in this example you can get away with small corrections. I've added tiny extensions in the angle that I want to place the arrow head in the examples.

I really recommend using nodes and coordinates for referring to known points. Also to avoid the repetitions you can create custom styles. `++` syntax is used for adding some coordinate to the last point of the current path. Finally `arc (start angle:end angle:xrad and yrad)` is sufficient.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
rotor/.style={inner sep=3pt,outer sep=0,fill opacity=0.3,minimum width=2cm,circle},
crossline/.style={gray,line width=3pt,opacity=0.5,line cap=round}
]

% cross
\draw[crossline] (-2,0) -- (2,0);
\draw[crossline] (0,-2) -- (0,2);

%rotors
\node[rotor,fill=blue,draw=blue] (n1) at (-2,0) {};
\node[rotor,fill=blue,draw=blue] (n2) at (2,0)  {};
\node[rotor,fill=red,draw=red]   (n3) at (0,-2) {};
\node[rotor,fill=red,draw=red]   (n4) at (0,2)  {};

% rotation direction arrows
\draw [->,line width=5pt] (n1) ++(140:5mm) arc (-220:40:5mm) --++(110:2mm);
\draw [->,line width=1pt] (n2) ++(140:5mm) arc (-220:40:5mm);
\draw [<-,line width=2.5pt] (n3) ++(138:5mm) --++(60:-1pt) arc (-220:40:5mm) ;
\draw [<-,line width=2.5pt] (n4) ++(138:5mm) --++(60:-1pt) arc (-220:40:5mm);

% rotors asterisk to indicate front and side
\draw plot[mark=asterisk,mark size=5pt,mark options={color=red}] coordinates {(-2,0)};
\draw plot[mark=asterisk,mark size=5pt,mark options={color=green}] coordinates {(2,0)};
\draw plot[mark=asterisk,mark size=5pt,mark options={color=cyan}] coordinates {(0,-2)};
\draw plot[mark=asterisk,mark size=5pt,mark options={color=red}] coordinates {(0,2)};

% translation direction
\node[fill=black,single arrow,minimum height=3cm] (arrow)  at (0,-3.5){};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how can I change the arrow tip to look like the bottom arrow? I tried adding `>=latex` to `tikzpicture` options, but then the thick tip get really ugly.

Comment: Instead of `->` which is the default arrow head you can use `-latex` but that arrow head is larger than the default so the correction needs to be more significant. You can replace that line with `\draw [-latex,line join=round,line width=5pt] (n1) ++(140:5mm) arc (-220:40:5mm) --++(110:3mm);` Single arrow is a node shape not an arrow head.

Comment: I know single arrow is a node shape, but I was wondering if it was possible to use that node shape (single arrow) as its is more elegante, IMO. This arrow with `->` looks like it's hand drawn.

Comment: You can not curve a node shape. But you have many arrow head options in the manual under the `arrow` library section.