# How can I improve the look of an arrowhead at the end of a small-radius arc?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows, arc

Arrow heads added to arches with small radius look ugly, they do not look symmetrical. Here is an example :

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
    \draw[->] (0,0) arc (00:290:.15cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

This gives an arrow like (screenshot of 24x magnification):

[image]

What I would like to have is something like:

[image]

Is it possible, how?

Comment: Take a look at [Create curved TikZ single arrow](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95936/create-curved-tikz-single-arrow) for one way of doing this.

Comment: With TikZ 3.0.0 you might want to have a look to `flexing` and `bending` libraries (untested).

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino it's enough to load `bending`. Could you turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: sure, I will do it tomorrow: this laptop is TikZ 3.0.0 free ;)

Comment: Hugely successful image of the problem. Google shows it, and you know the question is the one you want to ask.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

TikZ 3.0.0 provides a `bending` library for arrow tips placed on non-straight paths (see **16.3.8 Bending and Flexing** on pgfmanual).

Loading the library makes `flex=1` the default choice, but sometimes it worth to use custom values:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\draw[->] (0,0) arc (00:290:.15cm); % <= default flex=1
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\draw[-{>[flex=0.75]}] (0,0) arc (00:290:.15cm); % <= custom flex, better output
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output with `flex=1`:

[image]

Output with `flex=0.75`:

[image]

Comment: Notice that you can use this also in low-level `pgf`, as `\pgfsetarrowsend{Latex[flex=0.75]}` for example. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can add a small unseen straight line at the end - to correct the arrow direction. You can use the `shorten` option. Like this:

```
\documentclass{article}        
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
  \draw[->, shorten >=-1pt] (0,0) arc (00:290:.15cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Arc with arrow]

**Edit:**
This answer was written before I knew about *Bending and Flexing in the pgfmanual 16.3.8* that is specific for this purpose. See answer by @Claudio Fiandrino.