# Tikz: Curved parallel arrow around a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have a simple following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (2,0) circle (1.5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}`
```

I would like to create a curved parallel naming arrow around this circle as shown in the image.

[image]

Please help

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and complete your code to make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. This makes it easier to help and so more likely people will!

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66490/drawing-a-tikz-arc-specifying-the-center

Comment: This could also have relevance: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176779/how-can-i-improve-the-look-of-an-arrowhead-at-the-end-of-a-small-radius-arc/176781#176781

Comment: The quastion about drawing arc with given center was alos here http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34973/9335 and as I said `carc` is missing ;) But now we can easily create `\pic{carc}` !

Answer (score 6):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (2,0) circle (1.5cm);
\draw[-latex] (0.2,0) arc (180:120:1.8cm) node[near start,left] {$n$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eta

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Too_long;_didn%27t_read