# tweaking the positioning of tikz arrows (such as on a curved path)

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I believe that this is a duplicate of a question/answer posted within the past two months.  But, after much searching, I still can't find it.  Does someone out there know the link?

## My question

I'm not happy with the placement of the arrow in the following picture.  Anyone know how to correct the angle at which the arrow is attached to the arc?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm]
    \draw[help lines,blue!20,step=1] (0,0) grid (12,12);

    \draw[fill]  (0,0) coordinate [label=180:Z] (Z) circle (2pt);           %% center of the picture
    \draw[fill]  (5,5) coordinate [label=135:Q] (Q) circle (2pt);           %% center of the circle
    \draw[fill]  (Q) -- +(  0:6)   coordinate [label=0:A] (A) circle (2pt); %% first point on the circle
    %% drawing the circle
    \draw[blue]  (A) 
                 let \p1 = ($ (A) - (Q) $) in
                 arc(0:360:{veclen(\x1,\y1)});

    %% PROBLEMATIC LINES
    \draw [line width=0.4pt,red]
          let \p1 = ($(A) - (Q)$), \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
          (Q) -- +(320:\n1)
          coordinate (B) circle (2pt);




    \draw[purple,line width=0.4pt] 
          (B) -- +($  (0,0) ! 2em ! 0 : ($(B)-(Q)$)  $)  
          coordinate [label=center:B] (Bl) circle (6pt);

    \draw[blue]   
          ($ (B) ! 0.45 ! (Q) $) 
          coordinate (tC) circle (2pt);

    \draw[line width=1.5em,->]
          (tC) 
          let \p1 = ($(tC) - (Q)$) in
              arc ({atan2(\x1,\y1)}:{atan2(\x1,\y1)+90}:{veclen(\x1,\y1)});

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## UPDATE

OK, the link was found at [Create curved TikZ single arrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95942/22413), but I'm still having difficulty getting it to work.  Here's one example of what I've tried.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm]
    \draw[help lines,blue!20,step=1] (0,0) grid (12,12);

    \draw[fill]  (0,0) coordinate [label=180:Z] (Z) circle (2pt);           %% center of the picture
    \draw[fill]  (5,5) coordinate [label=135:Q] (Q) circle (2pt);           %% center of the circle
    \draw[fill]  (Q) -- +(  0:6)   coordinate [label=0:A] (A) circle (2pt); %% first point on the circle
    %% drawing the circle
    \draw[blue]  (A) 
                 let \p1 = ($ (A) - (Q) $) in
                 arc(0:360:{veclen(\x1,\y1)});

    %% PROBLEMATIC LINES
    \draw [line width=0.4pt,red]
          let \p1 = ($(A) - (Q)$), \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
          (Q) -- +(320:\n1)
          coordinate (B) circle (2pt);

    \draw[purple,line width=0.4pt] 
          (B) -- +($  (0,0) ! 2em ! 0 : ($(B)-(Q)$)  $)  
          coordinate [label=center:B] (Bl) circle (6pt);

    \draw[blue]   
          ($ (B) ! 0.45 ! (Q) $) 
          coordinate (tC) circle (2pt);

    \draw[line width=01.5em,->,end angle=230]
          (tC) 
          let \p1 = ($(tC) - (Q)$), 
              \n1={atan2(\x1,\y1)}, %% start angle
              \n2={\n1+90},         %% end angle
              \n3={veclen(\x1,\y1)} %% radius
          in
              arc (\n1:\n2:\n3)
              -- ++(\n2+90:\n3)
          %    -- ++(\n2+0:\n3)
             ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But there's a bit more length to the arrow than I want.

[image]

*A bit more hacking seems to get it*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm]
    \draw[help lines,blue!20,step=1] (0,0) grid (12,12);

    \draw[fill]  (0,0) coordinate [label=180:Z] (Z) circle (2pt);           %% center of the picture
    \draw[fill]  (5,5) coordinate [label=135:Q] (Q) circle (2pt);           %% center of the circle
    \draw[fill]  (Q) -- +(  0:6)   coordinate [label=0:A] (A) circle (2pt); %% first point on the circle
    %% drawing the circle
    \draw[blue]  (A) 
                 let \p1 = ($ (A) - (Q) $) in
                 arc(0:360:{veclen(\x1,\y1)});

    %% PROBLEMATIC LINES
    \draw [line width=0.4pt,red]
          let \p1 = ($(A) - (Q)$), \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
          (Q) -- +(320:\n1)
          coordinate (B) circle (2pt);

    \draw[purple,line width=0.4pt] 
          (B) -- +($  (0,0) ! 2em ! 0 : ($(B)-(Q)$)  $)  
          coordinate [label=center:B] (Bl) circle (6pt);

    \draw[blue]   
          ($ (B) ! 0.45 ! (Q) $) 
          coordinate (tC) circle (2pt);

    \draw[line width=01.5em,->]
          (tC) 
          let \p1 = ($(tC) - (Q)$), 
              \n1={atan2(\x1,\y1)}, %% start angle
              \n2={\n1+90},         %% end angle
              \n3={veclen(\x1,\y1)} %% radius
          in
              arc (\n1:\n2:\n3)
              -- ++(\n2+80:1em)
             ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76073/repositioning-and-resizing-arrow-tip-on-circular-arc-path?rq=1) the question you were talking about?

Comment: @UmarKalim.  Unfortunately not.  Notice that, if you change the width of the arrow to something such as `line width=0.4pt`, there's nothing apparently wrong in the appearance.  The visual problem arises on account of the line width.

Comment: Well, the arrow is placed parallel/orthogonal (depending on the view) to the `end angle`. That’s fixed and the rest is the ratio line width to radius. Where should it point to?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel.  I'd like to tweak it about 20 or 30 degrees clockwise.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, but I don't want the shaft of the arrow to be different.

Comment: Ah maybe this one? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95936/create-curved-tikz-single-arrow Still a tweak though

Comment: @percuße.  That's it!  So, can we mark this question as a duplicate and link it to that problem/question.

Comment: Voted for the duplicate

Comment: Hmmmm.  Well, I'm still open to suggestions of how to achieve this.  You got the correct link, but I'm having difficulty getting it to work as expected.