# TikZ - "Circled" arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

In the code below, I would like to add one text inside one "circled" arrow in gray like in the following ugly draw.

### Screenshot

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows,positioning}

    \tikzset{
        frame/.style={
            rectangle, draw,
            text width = 6em, text centered,
            minimum height = 4em, drop shadow, fill=lime!40,
            rounded corners,
        },
        line/.style={
            draw, -latex', rounded corners = 3mm,
        }
    }


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small\sffamily\bfseries,very thick,node distance = 4cm]
    \node [frame] (pop) {Population};
    \node [above=2cm, left of=pop] (init) {Initialisation};
    \node [below=2cm, left of=pop] (term) {Termination};
    \node [frame, above=2cm, right of=pop] (parents)  {Parents};
    \node [frame, below=2cm, right of=pop] (off)  {Offspring};

    \path [line] (parents)
     -- node[right,align=left,pos=.5] {Recombination\\[3mm]Mutation}
     (off);
    \path [line] (init) |- (pop.170);
    \path [line] (pop.190) -| (term);
    \path [line] (off) -| node[below,pos=.25, align=center] {Survivor\\ selection}(pop);
    \path [line] (pop) |- node[above,pos=.75, align=center] {Parents\\ selection}(parents);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related Question: [Drawing a circle around a node that looks like an arrow](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76058/drawing-a-circle-around-a-node-that-looks-like-an-arrow/).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**UPDATED**: New version supporting styles, and new example:

This command can be useful:

```
\def\circledarrow#1#2#3{ % #1 Style, #2 Center, #3 Radius
\draw[#1,->] (#2) +(80:#3) arc(80:-260:#3);
}
```

It can be used as part of a Tikz picture like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (text) {$n$ times};
\circledarrow{ultra thick, gray}{text}{1cm};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: my question becomes : "How to put this at the center of the triangle `Population-Parents-Offspring` ?".

Comment: There's no need of the final `;` for `\circledarrow` within `tikzpicture` unless you define it as `\def\circledarrow#1#2#3;{`. Only in that case you necessary need to use it.

Comment: @projetmbc check "barycentric systems" in the PGF/Tikz manual

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Yes, I know, but it doesn't hurt either (all text out of a tikz command inside a tikz environment is ignored, as it is the case for that semicolon). And I prefer how to looks the code with the `;`

Comment: @LionelMANSUY : it seems that I need to define coordinates. Isn't it ?

Comment: @projetmbc No, you already have them, since node names like `parents`, `off`, etc. can be used as coordinates. So you can get the center of the triangle by writing `(barycentric cs:pop=1,off=1,parents=1)`. You can use that (without the parenthesys) as the second argument of `\circledarrow` macro. Note that you can't write spaces between the commas in the barycentric coordinate system.

Comment: `\node at (barycentric cs:pop=1 ,parents=1 ,off=1) [color=gray] (insidetext) {N times}` and `\circledarrow{ultra thick, gray}{insidetext}{1cm}` do the jobs. Thanks a lot to everyone !

Answer (score 15):

My solution provides

- a new node shape `circle arrow`,
- three keys that work exactly like the keys for the `arc` operator:

  - `/qrr/circle arrow/start angle`,
  - `/qrr/circle arrow/end angle`,
  - `/qrr/circle arrow/delta angle`,
- and a key `/qrr/circle arrow/arrows` that sets the arrows for the arc.

I have also added a few styles the pre-set the direction and the open part of the circle.
Hopefully they are self-explanatory (see the example below).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=4pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    /qrr/circle arrow/.cd,
    start angle/.initial={},
    delta angle/.initial={},
    end angle/.initial={},
    arrows/.estore in=\qrr@ca@arrow,
    arrows=-
}
\pgfdeclareshape{circle arrow}{
    \inheritsavedanchors[from=circle] \inheritanchorborder[from=circle]
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north}      \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north west}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north east} \inheritanchor[from=circle]{center}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{west}       \inheritanchor[from=circle]{east}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid}        \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid west}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid east}   \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base west}  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base east}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south}      \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south west}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south east}
    \backgroundpath{
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/qrr/circle arrow/start angle}\qrr@ca@s
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/qrr/circle arrow/end angle}\qrr@ca@e
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/qrr/circle arrow/delta angle}\qrr@ca@d
        \ifx\qrr@ca@s\pgfutil@empty%
            \pgfmathsetmacro\qrr@ca@s{\qrr@ca@e-\qrr@ca@d}%
        \else
            \ifx\qrr@ca@e\pgfutil@empty%
                \pgfmathsetmacro\qrr@ca@e{\qrr@ca@s+\qrr@ca@d}%
            \fi%
        \fi
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointadd{\centerpoint}{\pgfpointpolar{\qrr@ca@s}{\radius}}}%
        \pgfpatharc{\qrr@ca@s}{\qrr@ca@e}{\radius}%
        \pgfkeys{/tikz/arrows/.expand once=\qrr@ca@arrow}%
    }
}
\makeatother
\tikzset{% the first two styles are internal, they do not work alone!
    turn left/.style={/tikz/shape=circle arrow,/qrr/circle arrow/arrows=->,/qrr/circle arrow/delta angle=340},
    turn right/.style={/tikz/shape=circle arrow,/qrr/circle arrow/arrows=<-,/qrr/circle arrow/delta angle=340},
    turn left north/.style  = {/tikz/turn left,  /qrr/circle arrow/start angle=100} ,
    turn left east/.style   = {/tikz/turn left,  /qrr/circle arrow/start angle=10},
    turn left south/.style  = {/tikz/turn left,  /qrr/circle arrow/start angle=280},
    turn left west/.style   = {/tikz/turn left,  /qrr/circle arrow/start angle=190},
    turn right north/.style = {/tikz/turn right, /qrr/circle arrow/start angle=100} ,
    turn right east/.style  = {/tikz/turn right, /qrr/circle arrow/start angle=10},
    turn right south/.style = {/tikz/turn right, /qrr/circle arrow/start angle=280},
    turn right west/.style  = {/tikz/turn right, /qrr/circle arrow/start angle=190},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes,draw=none,row sep=1em,column sep=1em,
    every node/.style={draw=gray,ultra thick, inner sep=.5em,font=$n$ times}
] (m) {
    |[turn left north]|  & |[turn left east]|   \\
    |[turn left west]|   & |[turn left south]|  \\
    |[turn right north]| & |[turn right east]|  \\
    |[turn right west]|  & |[turn right south]| \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Of course, defining a new node shape is _the right way to do it_, but I was too lazy. +1

Answer (score 8):

Just like this, with appropriates values:

```
\draw[->,>=latex'] (pointA) arc[radius=1cm,start angle=0,delta angle=270];
```