# Mutual coupling and Circuitikz?

Tags: circuitikz

I am desperately trying to draw mutual coupling between two inductors, something like this:

[image: M between the two curved arrows.]

or

[image: M above the curved arrow.]

where the actual focus is on the mutual coupling M of the two coils. When I searched the web, I stepped over these two image which were part of a lecture on electrical circuits. Apparently, they are done using Circuitikz, but i was unable do identify the author to ask him directly.

So for example, I would like to add mutual between these two coils:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[siunitx,europeanresistors,cuteinductors,americanvoltages,americancurrents]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw (0,0)
  to[sV=$V_0$] (0,2)
  to[L=$L_1$] (2,2)
  to[short] (2,0)
  to[L=$L_2$] (0,0) ;
\end{circuitikz}
 \caption{Two coils without mutual coupling.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Very nice diagrams!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is one possible solution. amssymb is used for loop currents.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[siunitx,cuteinductors,americanvoltages,americancurrents]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{latexsym,amssymb,amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw (0,0) to [R=$R_1$] (2,0) -| (3,-1) to [L,l_=$L_1$] (3,-3) |- (-1,-4) to [V,l=$v_g$] (-1,0) -- (0,0)
(1,-2) node[scale=6]{$\circlearrowright$}
(1,-2) node{$I_1$};
\draw (5,0) to [short] (7,0) -| (8,-1) to [R=$R_2$,] (8,-3) |- (4,-4) to [L,l_=$L_2$] (4,0) -- (4,0) --(5,0)
(6,-2) node[scale=6]{$\circlearrowleft$}
(6,-2) node{$I_2$};
\draw [fill=black] (2.5,-1)node(a){} circle (2pt);
\draw [fill=black] (4.5,-3)node(b){} circle (2pt);
\draw [<->,>=stealth] (a)  to [bend left] node[pos=0.5,fill=white] {M} ++(2,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw (0,0) to [R=$R_1$,i=$I_1$] (2,0) -| (3,-1) to [L,l_=$L_1$] (3,-3) |- (-1,-4)   to [V,v=$v_g$] (-1,0) -- (0,0)
(1,-2) node[scale=1.5]{$M\frac{di_2}{dt}L_1\frac{di_1}{dt}$};
\draw(1,-0.5)node{-} to [open] (1,-3.5)node(){+}; % adding polarities
\draw(2,-0.5)node{+} to [open] (2,-3.5)node(){-}; % adding polarities
\draw (5,0) to [short,i<=$I_2$] (7,0)  -| (8,-1)   to [R=$R_2$,] (8,-3) |- (4,-4)   to [L,l_=$L_2$] (4,0)  -- (4,0) --(5,0) 
(6,-2) node[scale=1.5]{$L_2\frac{di_2}{dt}M\frac{di_1}{dt}$};
\draw(5,-0.5)node{+} to [open] (5,-3.5)node(){-}; % adding polarity
\draw(6,-0.5)node{-} to [open] (6,-3.5)node(){+}; % adding polarity

\draw [fill=black] (2.5,-1)node(a){} circle (2pt);
\draw [fill=black] (4.5,-3)node(b){} circle (2pt);
\draw [<->,>=stealth] (a)  to [bend left] node[pos=0.5,fill=white] {M} ++(2,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, that's pretty much what I was searching for!

Comment: One more question, what's the function of the two ++ signs at the end? I couldn't figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: OK, that means relative to the (a) point. -- (x_a,y_a)+(2,0) -- So horizontally to the right of 2cm, relative to point a.

Comment: Got it! Seems like it makes no difference to have one + or two ++ signs... Thanks again, you saved my day!

Comment: No. they are different. Two ++ is relative to the previous coordinate. One + is relative to the FIRST/STARTING coordinates of all points in the command line. But in this case, they are same indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Jesse provided you an answer with your coupling question, this show how you can use `tikz` to draw the circular arrows so that you have matching arrow heads and also the ability to control the color:

[image]

### References:

- [How to put a symbol inside a circle arrow?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29841/how-to-put-a-symbol-inside-a-circle-arrow/29856#29856)
- [TikZ - "Circled" arrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95221/tikz-circled-arrow).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[siunitx,europeanresistors,cuteinductors,americanvoltages,americancurrents]{circuitikz}

\usepackage{calc}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29841/how-to-put-a-symbol-inside-a-circle-arrow/29856#29856
\makeatletter
\newlength\@SizeOfCirc%
\newcommand{\CricArrowRight}[2][]{%
    \setlength{\@SizeOfCirc}{\maxof{\widthof{#2}}{\heightof{#2}}}%
    \tikz [x=1.0ex,y=1.0ex,line width=.20ex, draw=black, fill=black, -stealth, #1]%
        \draw [anchor=center]%
            node (0,0) {#2}%
            (0,1.2\@SizeOfCirc) arc (85:-240:1.2\@SizeOfCirc);%
}%
\newcommand{\CricArrowLeft}[2][]{\CricArrowRight[xscale=-1,#1]{#2}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw (0,0) to [R=$R_1$] (2,0) -| (3,-1) to [L,l_=$L_1$] (3,-3) |- (-1,-4) to [V,l=$v_g$] (-1,0) -- (0,0)
(1,-2) node{\CricArrowRight[draw=cyan, fill=cyan, text=red]{$I_1$}};
\draw (5,0) to [short] (7,0) -| (8,-1) to [R=$R_2$,] (8,-3) |- (4,-4) to [L,l_=$L_2$] (4,0) -- (4,0) --(5,0)
(6,-2) node{\CricArrowLeft{$I_2$}};
\draw [fill=black] (2.5,-1)node(a){} circle (2pt);
\draw [fill=black] (4.5,-3)node(b){} circle (2pt);
\draw [<->,>=stealth] (a)  to [bend left] node[pos=0.5,fill=white] {M} ++(2,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```