# how to put curly arrow inside a rectangle....tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

This is a tikz question. Its a long code so I am adding the line that needs help

```
\draw[black,thick,fill=white] ($(c2i.north west)+(-0.0,0.0)$)  rectangle ($(c3i.south east)+(0.0,-0.0)$);
```

This is a rectangle. Now I want to place a curly arrow in its middle.
I saw

[Mutual coupling and Circuitikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211126/mutual-coupling-and-circuitikz)

[How to put a symbol inside a circle arrow?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29841/how-to-put-a-symbol-inside-a-circle-arrow)

and tried

```
\draw[black,thick,fill=white] ($(c2i.north west)+(-0.0,0.0)$)  rectangle ($(c3i.south east)+(0.0,-0.0)$) {$\circlearrowleft$};
```

but this isn't working. Can someone help here. I have included required packages but I think its a syntax problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why `($(c2i.north west)+(-0.0,0.0)$)`? If you add or subtract zero, then just say `(c2i.north west)`.

In any case, you're adding text without a node, so that's not going to work. You have two options:

1. Replace the rectangle with a node, you can use the `fit` library to fit to those two coordinates.
2. Draw the rectangle, then place a node like `\node at ($(c2i.north west)!.5!(c3i.south east)$) {$\circlearrowleft$};`

The first solution is the better one, one less command to achieve the same result.

Comment: Or draw the rectangle around the node itself using: `\node[draw] {$\circlearrowleft$}`. Optionally using `inner sep` to change the size of the rectangle.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working but now I see its very small as compared to my rectangle. My question 1) how do I change its thickness? 2)How do I make it big?

Comment: @NAASI Sorry, I'm not sure I'm understanding: please include a minimal example in your question, so I can see the code you're working on.

Comment: I used \node at ($(c2i.north west)!.5!(c3i.south east)$) {$\circlearrowleft$}; and its working fine. I am asking what should I do to change size of arrow i-e make it a bigger circle and how to change its line thickness

Comment: @NAASI Ah that. Well, it's text, so it works like text, you cannot act on it differently. You could try changing the font, or directly trying to build the arrow yourself. In the second case I could help, but you should post your code for me to test.

Comment: many thanks.....I didn't notice thats its a text. Fixed...