# Circular orientation arrow

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I am trying to create the following image in tikz.
[image]

But the problem is that I am not able to draw the circular arrows as needed. Instead, my figure looks like this:
[image]

How can I add the orientation arrows?

The code I used is as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{rvwvcq}{rgb}{0.08,0.4,0.75}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [line width=2pt] (-1,2)-- (-1,0);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-1,0)-- (-3.98,-0.3);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-3.98,-0.3)-- (-1,2);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-1,0)-- (-4,3);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-4,3)-- (-1,2);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-1,2)-- (2,2);
\draw [line width=2pt] (2,2)-- (-1,0);
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-1,2) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=rvwvcq] (-0.89,2.29) node {$A$};
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-1,0) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=rvwvcq] (-0.89,0.29) node {$B$};
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-3.98,-0.3) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=rvwvcq] (-3.88,-0.02) node {$C$};
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-4,3) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=rvwvcq] (-3.89,3.29) node {$D$};
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (2,2) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=rvwvcq] (2,2.29) node {$E$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Maybe help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95223/31034

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to propose to make the code shorter by making use of some of the features of Ti*k*Z like symbolic coordinates, and to use bent arrows.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{rvwvcq}{rgb}{0.08,0.4,0.75}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,inner sep=2.5pt,draw,fill=rvwvcq,
label={[text=rvwvcq,anchor=south west,inner sep=1pt,font=\scriptsize]:$#1$},
name=#1,node contents={}}]
 \path (-1,2) node[bullet=A] (-1,0) node[bullet=B]
  (-3.98,-0.3) node[bullet=C] (-4,3) node[bullet=D]
  (2,2) node[bullet=E];
 \draw[line width=2pt] (A)-- (D) -- (B) -- (E) -- (A) -- (C) -- (B) -- (A); 
 \path (-2,1) coordinate (H); % auxiliary
 \foreach \X/\Y/\Z in {A/D/H,B/C/H,A/B/E}
 {\draw[thick,-{Latex[bend]}] (barycentric cs:\X=1,\Y=1,\Z=1) + (-120:0.2)
 arc(-120:180:0.2);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if I don't want the bent arrows (I mean the tip of the arrow)?

Comment: @user473334 Just remove `[bend]`.

Comment: Will do that, thanks.