# Circlearrowright with specific center and radium

Tags: circuitikz

How can I draw in circuitikz a "circlearrowright" centered in (11,-2) with radium 3cm ? (and what packages I need?) Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As it stands the question seems  a bit too vague. Can you clarify?

Comment: Well, I have an circuit and I must add some "oriented circles" (loop) whith sepcific radiums in specific places, something like:\begin{circuitikz} \draw circlearrowright \end{circuitikz}

Comment: nobody?????? :(

Comment: something like this?
`\draw [-latex, thick]
      (11, -2) %centre of the circle
    ++(0:3cm)  %start the arc 'radius'cm away from centre
  arc (0:270:3cm); %arc from 0deg to 270deg with radius`

Comment: ca you please remove the comments? (ie %....) because when I copy I don't know when to press newline :D

Comment: @npatrat I was not aware that newlines were removed from comments.

Comment: Does [Drawing a circle around a node that looks like an arrow](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76058/drawing-a-circle-around-a-node-that-looks-like-an-arrow) answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you intended.

The first coordinate after the `\draw` command moves the current pen position to the circle's centre. The next coordinate marked by `++()` moves the pen *relative* to current position. Now the `arc` is drawn from the current pen position with the *starting angle*, up to the *ending angle* with a specified *radius*.

Note that *the angle specified in the relative movement must be the same as the starting angle of the arc*.

```
\documentclass[12pt, tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
%% below code required only for MWE
\useasboundingbox (7,-6) rectangle (15,2);
\node [fill, circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2pt](mycentre) at (11,-2){};
\node [below of=mycentre] {$(11,-2)$};

%below code is for the circle with arrow
\draw [-latex, thick]
      (11, -2) %centre of the circle
    ++(0:3cm)  %start the arc 'radius'cm away from centre
  arc (0:270:3cm); %arc from 0deg to 270deg with radius
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: circle arrow]