# What package is needed for \circlearrowright and \circlearrowleft?

Tags: symbols, arrows

On a few pages I found that the command for a clockwise arrow should be \circlearrowright:

- *[\circlearrowright - Tex Command](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tex_commands/circlearrowright.htm)*
- *[LaTeX circlearrowright symbol](https://docs.latexbase.com/symbols/circlearrowright/)*
- *[The great, big list of LaTeX symbols](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Enmark/UsefulFacts/LaTeX_symbols.pdf)*

But, when I try it, I just get:

```
Undefined control sequence. \circlearrowright
```

I am using the package amsmath and additionally tried mathcomp. What do I need more?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21360/134144 may be useful, especially the remark about the Latex symbol list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [current version](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive) of the document "The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List", maintained by Scott Pakin and featuring more than 18000 symbols and associated macros, the following six packages provide macros called `\circlearrowright` and `\circlearrowleft` for use under pdfLaTeX:

- amssymb
- mathabx
- MnSymbol
- fdsymbol
- boisik
- stix

If you employ the `unicode-math` package (and hence either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX), there are several unicode math fonts that provide macros called `\circlearrowright` and `\circlearrowleft` directly -- no need to load a separate math font package.

Answer (score 13):

Can't resist to show the other possible way to find it, at https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html:

[image]

I have the app on my phone and it's a lifesaver when writing math...

Comment: thanks for the hint, that looks great :D
I will definitely have a look at it.